# VM Terminal stops automatically in google cloud compute engine instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am first time user for google cloud. I am trying to run a script that probably takes 15 hours to run. I set an instance in google compute engine to run tensorflow. The instance also has one GPU. After I ssh into the instance and set everything up, I started to run the script through the shell, but the script seems to stop automatically after 10 mins after I am inactive on my computer. When I click on that shell again, it would automatically reconnect me to it. Wondering what I should do so that it doesn't automatically stop.

Comment: It might be as simple as running your script nohup (see https://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup)

Comment: 1) Use a program like `screen` or `tmux` which keeps your session running. If you are disconnected you can reconnect to the running session. 2) Change your SSH settings to not disconnect you on idle. I leave SSH sessions open for weeks without problems.

Comment: @JohnHanley how do i change the ssh session ?

Comment: You will need to look this up in the documentation for the command you are using. Look for a feature similar to "idle sessions".